# C# ComboBox e SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Gostaria de saber como carregar valores em um combobox, listando uma coluna inteira do banco de dados, por exemplo, tenho uma coluna que se chama "Cerveja" e tem vários nomes, gostaria de listar essa coluna em um ComboBox. Valeu.

Tenho um Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoadCerveja]
(
    @Cerveja varchar(60)
)
AS
    SELECT @cerveja from Ingredientes
RETURN
```

e no código preciso adicionar no formLoad pra ele puxar pro ComboBox a coluna "Cerveja" do banco de dados.

Tentei fazer o seguinte(no form load)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
conexao.Open();
SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("LoadIngredients", conexao);
cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdd.Parameters.Add("@Cerveja");
SqlDataReader DR;
DR = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
{
 comboBox1.Items.Add(DR.GetValue()); **// Não sei o que fazer aqui pra        adicionar      os dados ao combobox !!!!**
}
else MessageBox.Show("Erro ao buscar receita no DB.");
```

}

Comment: Poderia adicionar mais informações na pergunta? Vai ficar melhor para ajudar vc se tiver mais informações. Tem algum código onde vc tenta carregar as informações no combobox?

Comment: Ja editei aqui, valeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um exemplo na documentação sobre o [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)..

```
....
    SqlDataReader DR = cmdd.ExecuteReader();

    if (DR.HasRows)
    {
      while (DR.Read())
      {
          comboBox1.Items.Add(DR.GetString(0)); 
      }
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
    }
    DR.Close();
....
```

No seu parameters você pode inserir o valor de duas maneiras

```
cmdd.Parameters.Add("@Cerveja", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "valor"
```

ou

```
cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cerveja", valor);
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio marcos giovanni!

Eu estou com um problema na linha cmdd.Parameters.Add("@Cerveja");

O parâmetro tá errado e eu não sei como arrumar, precisa-se de um objeto value...

Comment: Editei a resposta..

Comment: Fiz sem usar stored procedure, criei uma string com a instrução select e funcionou, valeu meu brother era exatamente isso

Comment: Beleza!! Então marca como resposta certa, no V, logo abaixo das setas de pontos da resposta ^^